# Central connecting to multiple BLE peripherals?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible for an android app to read data from multiple BLE peripherals at the same time, or would you have to connect to multiple peripherals sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect to up to 4 devices simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, is there any kind of documentation on this I can read so I can learn the details?

Comment: This is not fully true. It all depends on android device. Some really bad ones have 4 but good Samsung devices have 15. Sometimes the hardware has support for many but software restricts to fewer (by stupidity), e.g. Nexus 6P which has support for 15 but the default OS restricts to 7. Unfortunately this is usually totally undocumented.

Comment: That's too bad. My goal is to be able to read data from multiple temperature sensors at the same time

Comment: You dont need to connect to read data, most of these sensors act as BLE beacons where data can be read without connecting as its embedded in the beacon broadcast. So in theory there is no limit... https://developers.google.com/beacons/